# Openpyxl looses spreadsheet formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write a python script using openpyxl to open an excel spreadsheet and a csv file from a local server.  If certain conditions are met, I want lines from the csv file written to the next available line in the excel file.

My code achieves this, but I loose all my formatting in the rest of the workbook.  How do I get openpyxl to merely add information to my spreadsheet without changing formatting elsewhere?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('SPC.xlsx')
sht = wb.active
date = str(sht['A1'].value) + str(sht['B1'].value) + str(sht['C1'].value) + '00'
url = 'http://10.5.190.4/logs/Run_Data/'+date+'.CSV'
csv = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
lines = csv.split('\n')
number = sht['F2'].value
i = 0
i1 = 1
i2 = 0
sht['A1'].value = 26
while lines[i] !='':
data = lines[1].split(',')
if data[2] == 'ON' and data[16] != '0':
    if data[3] == '' or data[4] == '' or data[5] == '':
        while i1 < 17:          
            sht.cell(row = number, column = i1).value = data[i1-1]
            i1 = i1 + 1
            i2 = i2 + 1
        number = number + 1
        i1 = 1
        i = i + 1
    else:
        while i1 < 17:          
            sht.cell(row = number, column = i1).value = data[i1-1]
            i1 = i1 + 1
            i2 = i2 + 1
        number = number + 1
        i1 = 1
        i = i + 1    
else:
    i = i + 1
wb.save('SPC.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at the notes here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

Comment: If you have a specific text styling that you're trying to maintain, then you're going to need to read the last styled line and specify that styling to use in the cells you want to write to. [See here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/styles.html) Also, for syntactic sugar, you can change all of your "i1 = i1 + 1" to "i1 += 1", which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

openpyxl does not strip formatting from existing workbooks. Please create a bug report with a sample file and script if you think that there is a problem.

Comment: Forgive me if I am missing an obvious solution, but it seems that openpyxl /does/ remove things like $ signs and commas from numeric values in a spreadsheet. I understand why it is useful to be able to retrieve an integer, but is there a simple way to get a string with those things included?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, after opening file with `openpyxl`, update it then save it I did loose the formatting information.

Also I got an error message as follow (much more a warning): `Discarded range with reserved name`.

I finally realised that I was reading / writing the excel file using index starting from `0`. But `Row0` and `Col0` doesn't exists in Excel.

After changing starting value from "0" to "1), now everything is fine.